# ¿Deben usarse las preposiciones para las siglas?

Tags: siglas

Según,

[Sigla significado](https://www.google.com/search?q=sigla%20significado&source=hp&ei=a7UcY8jxJ7341sQPwo60sAI&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYxzDe3zaI1mzwWWh3-1UXY8Do2OfV6Lz&ved=0ahUKEwiI04f6zIr6AhU9vJUCHUIHDSYQ4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=sigla%20significado&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCggAEOoCELQCEEMyCggAEOoCELQCEEMyCggAEOoCELQCEEMyCggAEOoCELQCEEMyCggAEOoCELQCEEMyCggAEOoCELQCEEMyCggAEOoCELQCEEMyCggAEOoCELQCEEMyCggAEOoCELQCEEMyCggAEOoCELQCEENQAFilFmDnF2gBcAB4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAKABAbABCg&sclient=gws-wiz)

> Abreviatura formada por las letras iniciales de un sintagma,
> normalmente nombres de instituciones, empresas, etc.

¿Qué hay de las preposiciones? ¿Deben usarse estas en las siglas, deben no usarse, o es opcional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 8. Las siglas suelen omitir para su formación los artículos, las preposiciones y las conjunciones que aparecen en la denominación completa, salvo cuando se desea facilitar su pronunciación, convirtiéndolas en acrónimos

<sub>*[RAE](https://www.rae.es/dpd/sigla)*</sub>

De lo que se deduce que su uso es arbitrario, excepto cuanto son necesarias para la fonética de la sigla, pasando esta a ser un acrónimo. Tal el caso de **ENDESA**: Empresa Nacional De Electricidad, Sociedad Anónima.